# IGNORE 1 LINES in MySQL PDO PHP Command Line Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I am using a PHP script via command line to load a CSV file into MySQL via a PDO statement. The import itself executes successfully... except the first line is not being ignored with `IGNORE 1 LINES`

The CSV file: http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/free-zipcode-database.csv

(error checking removed for brevity, full SQL left in for completeness)

```
<?php //import_zips.php

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'dbuser';
$db_pass        = 'dbpass';
$db_name        = 'dbname';
$input_file     = "free-zipcode-database.csv";
$fieldseperator = ",";
$lineseperator  = "\n";
$fieldsenclosed = '"';
$test_table     = "test_zipcodes";

if(!file_exists($input_file)) {
  die("File not found.");
}

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass,
  array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  )
);

$pdo->exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$test_table);

$pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE `".$test_table."` (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `zipcode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, `city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL, `location_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, `lat` double DEFAULT NULL, `lon` double DEFAULT NULL, `xaxis` double DEFAULT NULL, `yaxis` double DEFAULT NULL, `zaxis` double DEFAULT NULL, `worldregion` char(2) DEFAULT NULL, `country` char(2) DEFAULT '', `location_text` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, `location` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, `decommisioned` char(5) DEFAULT NULL, `tax_returns_filed` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, `estimated_population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, `total_wages` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");

try {
  $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($input_file)." INTO TABLE `$test_table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseperator)." OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldsenclosed)."
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseperator))." IGNORE 1 LINES";
  echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records.\n";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die($e->getMessage()."\n");
}
```

The script executes successfully (with a side effect of `IGNORE 1 LINES` appended to `$affectedRows`.)

```
$ php import_zips.php
Loaded a total of 81831 IGNORE 1 LINES records.
```

The problem is that the first row of the CSV is not being ignored and ends up in the table. Basically, the `IGNORE 1 LINES` is being ignored.

I have a workaround for now (manually deleting the first line of the CSV) but would like to have a better solution as to how to get this to work correctly.

---

PHP Version

```
PHP 5.5.23 (cli) (built: Mar 23 2015 01:47:37)
```

MySQL Version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.9, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Running on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: The closing `)` for `$pdo->exec` is before `"IGNORE 1 LINES"`, thank's for the correct detailed question, but this is only a typo

Comment: You are absolutely right, doh moment for sure.... thanks!

Comment: Had this exact same issue just now. Glad I found this question. I was looking at it forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction:

```
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($input_file)." INTO TABLE `$test_table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseperator)." OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldsenclosed)."
LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseperator)." IGNORE 1 LINES");
```